# How to generate camera rays for ray casting

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, raycasting, rotational-matrices

I am trying to make a simple voxel engine with OpenGL and C++. My first step is to send out rays from the camera and detect if the ray intersected with something (for testing purposes its just two planes). I have got it working with without the camera rotating by creating a full screen quad and programming the fragment shader to send out a ray for every fragment (for now I'm just assuming a fragment is a pixel) which is in the direction texCoord.x, texCoord.y, -1. Now I am trying to implement camera rotation.

I have tried to generate a rotation matrix within the cpu and send that to the shader which will multiply it with every ray. However, when I rotate the camera, the planes start to stretch in a way which I can only describe with this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NScMwnPe8c

Here is the code that creates the matrix and is run every frame:

```
float pi = 3.141592;
// camRotX and Y are defined elsewhere and can be controlled from the keyboard during runtime.
glm::vec3 camEulerAngles = glm::vec3(camRotX, camRotY, 0);

std::cout << "X: " << camEulerAngles.x << " Y: " << camEulerAngles.y << "\n";

// Convert to radians
camEulerAngles.x = camEulerAngles.x * pi / 180;
camEulerAngles.y = camEulerAngles.y * pi / 180;
camEulerAngles.z = camEulerAngles.z * pi / 180;

// Generate Quaternian
glm::quat camRotation;
camRotation = glm::quat(camEulerAngles);

// Generate rotation matrix from quaternian
glm::mat4 camToWorldMatrix = glm::toMat4(camRotation);
// No transformation matrix is created because the rays should be relative to 0,0,0

// Send the rotation matrix to the shader
int camTransformMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "cameraTransformationMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(camTransformMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(camToWorldMatrix));
```

And the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec4 texCoord;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform vec3 cameraTR;
uniform vec3 cameraTL;
uniform vec3 cameraBR;
uniform vec3 cameraBL;
uniform mat4 cameraTransformationMatrix;
uniform float fov;
uniform float aspectRatio;
float pi = 3.141592;

int RayHitCell(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, vec3 cellPosition, float cellSize)
{
    if(direction.z != 0)
    {
        float multiplicationFactorFront = cellPosition.z - origin.z;
        if(multiplicationFactorFront > 0){
            vec2 interceptFront = vec2(direction.x * multiplicationFactorFront + origin.x,
                                       direction.y * multiplicationFactorFront + origin.y);
            if(interceptFront.x > cellPosition.x && interceptFront.x < cellPosition.x + cellSize &&
               interceptFront.y > cellPosition.y && interceptFront.y < cellPosition.y + cellSize)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        float multiplicationFactorBack = cellPosition.z + cellSize - origin.z;
        if(multiplicationFactorBack > 0){
            vec2 interceptBack = vec2(direction.x * multiplicationFactorBack + origin.x,
                                      direction.y * multiplicationFactorBack + origin.y);
            if(interceptBack.x > cellPosition.x && interceptBack.x < cellPosition.x + cellSize &&
               interceptBack.y > cellPosition.y && interceptBack.y < cellPosition.y + cellSize)
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    // For now I'm not accounting for FOV and aspect ratio because I want to get the rotation working first
    vec4 beforeRotateRayDirection = vec4(texCoord.x,texCoord.y,-1,0);
    // Apply the rotation matrix that was generated on the cpu
    vec3 rayDirection = vec3(cameraTransformationMatrix *  beforeRotateRayDirection);

    int t = RayHitCell(cameraPosition, rayDirection, vec3(0,0,5), 1);
    if(t == 1)
    {
        // Hit front plane
        color = vec4(0, 0, 1, 0);
    }else if(t == 2)
    {
        // Hit back plane
        color = vec4(0, 0, 0.5, 0);
    }else{
        // background color
        color = vec4(0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: see [How to best write a voxel engine in C with performance in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214) ... basically you will generate direction in vertex shader by substracting camera focus from vertex position and normalize  ... while rendering single QUAD covering znear plane (whole screen/view) fragment position is start of ray and interpolated direction from vertex is the direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Its really hard to know what is wrong, I will try non-theless.

### Here are few tips and notes:

1) You can debug directions by mapping them to RGB color. Keep in mind you should normalize the vectors and map from `(-1,1)` to `(0,1)`. Just do the `dir*0.5+1.0` type of thing. Example:

```
color = vec4(normalize(rayDirection) * 0.5, 0) + vec4(1);
```

2) You can get the rotation matrix in a more straight manner. Quaternion is initialized from an forward direction, it will first rotate around Y axis (horizontal look) then, **and only then**, around X axis (vertical look). Keep in mind that the rotations order is implementation dependent if you initialize from euler-angles. Use mat4_cast to avoid experimental glm extension (gtx) whenever possible. Example:

```
// Define rotation quaternion starting from look rotation
glm::quat camRotation = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
camRotation = glm::rotate(camRotation, glm::radians(camRotY), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
camRotation = glm::rotate(camRotation, glm::radians(camRotX), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
glm::mat4 camToWorldMatrix = glm::mat4_cast(camRotation);
```

3) Your `beforeRotateRayDirection` is a vector that (probably) points from (-1,-1,-1) all the way to (1,1,-1). Which is **not normalized**, the length of (1,1,1) is √3 ≈ 1.7320508075688772... Be sure you have taken that into account for your collision math or just normalize the vector.

### My partial answer so far...

Your collision test is a bit weird... It appears you want to cast the ray into the Z plane for the given cell position (but twice, one for the front and one for the back). I have reviewed your code logic and it makes some sense, but without the vertex program, thus not knowing what the `texCoord` range values are, it is not possible to be sure. You might want to rethink your logic to something like this:

```
int RayHitCell(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, vec3 cellPosition, float cellSize)
{
    //Get triangle side vectors
    vec3 tu = vec3(cellSize,0,0);   //Triangle U component
    vec3 tv = vec3(0,cellSize,0);   //Triangle V component

    //Determinant for inverse matrix
    vec3 q = cross(direction, tv);
    float det = dot(tu, q);
    //if(abs(det) < 0.0000001) //If too close to zero
    //  return;
    float invdet = 1.0/det;

    //Solve component parameters
    vec3 s = origin - cellPosition;
    float u = dot(s, q) * invdet;
    if(u < 0.0 || u > 1.0)
        return 0;

    vec3 r = cross(s, tu);
    float v = dot(direction, r) * invdet;
    if(v < 0.0 || v > 1.0)
        return 0;

    float t = dot(tv, r) * invdet;
    if(t <= 0.0)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

void main()
{
    // For now I'm not accounting for FOV and aspect ratio because I want to get the 
    // rotation working first
    vec4 beforeRotateRayDirection = vec4(texCoord.x, texCoord.y, -1, 0);
    // Apply the rotation matrix that was generated on the cpu
    vec3 rayDirection = vec3(cameraTransformationMatrix * beforeRotateRayDirection);

    int t = RayHitCell(cameraPosition, normalize(rayDirection), vec3(0,0,5), 1);
    if (t == 1)
    {
        // Hit front plane
        color = vec4(0, 0, 1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        // background color
        color = vec4(0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

This should give you a plane, let me know if it works. A cube will be very easy to do.

PS.: `u` and `v` can be used for texture mapping.

Comment: Updating the RayHitCell function made it work perfectly. I thought the problem had something to do with the rotation matrix so I guess that's why I was not finding the solution. You've made my day - you have no idea how long I have been working on this problem for :)

Comment: Nice to know! If you need any help adjusting the function for the other voxel faces, let me know. Keep in mind that You will probably have precision issues if you move farther away from the origin (0,0,0). I think you can handle it by subtracting the camera position from the cell position, somewhat close to how it's done with a MVP matrix (the 'view' part especially).

Comment: Although, I have managed to get this working for a cube by using different tu and tv values for each face (which I found through trial and error) I don't really understand how the function works. Could you point me to a site that explains this visually or a search term that I could use to find out more? Also, how can I find the world space position the intersection occurs? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing! The logic is an optimized version of this algorithmn [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection), look over at the parametric form. In our instance, 'u' and 'v' are the components of the collision hit projected into the cell plane and 't' is it projected into the ray itself.

There are 2 ways to get the hit position, you can either use 't':

    `vec3 hitPos = origin + direction * t`

Or you can use 'u' and 'v':

    `vec3 hitPos = planeOrigin + u * tu + v * tv`

Comment: By trial and error, I found that the second one is less prone to give float precision errors...

Comment: The whole algoritmn is the inversion of the matrix pointed out in the link, the single `u`, `v` and `t` declaration lines are those of the line * collumn multiplication of the two matrices pointed in this image [link](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/3ece713463bcca14445cb33405e3d706a6c1c570)